# Each array representing a bit pattern

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to implement extendible hashing. It will use buckets to store ID's which are taken from a text file. Each id (i.e. 10110110111) will go into a bucket that has a fixed size. Each bucket will be an array of nodes. What my big problem is I am trying to determine how each bucket will be represented by a bit pattern. Example:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Each bucket will be representing (at least 1) of the above bit patterns. If a bucket reaches the max that it can hold (which is a fixed size), and something else needs to go in it, the bit pattern will increase by 1 digit so it will now be 0000, 0001, 0010...etc

Essentially, I am just quite confused as to how I would make each bucket represent at least one bit pattern so that I can compare each id to the bit pattern of each bucket and find an appropriate spot for it.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Please show some examples of what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use integers to represent the ID. You can compare them to the bitstring from your textfile using `Integer.toBinaryString(myId);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make each bucket represent a unique number. May be start from 0 and increment by 1. This number would be an integer of base 10. But save your bucket pattern by converting it to binary.

```
Integer.toString(x, 2)
```

and if you need to convert it back to binary, you can do that this way

```
Integer.valueOf(binary_value, 2)
```